# Eas update gives scheme error in expo managed app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, eas

When I try to push an update i get this error:
✔ Exported bundle(s)
√ Uploaded 2 app bundles
√ Uploading assets skipped - no new assets found
i 45 iOS assets, 45 Android assets (maximum: 2000 total per update). Learn more about asset limits.: https://expo.fyi/eas-update-asset-limits
✖ Failed to publish updates
Manifest Validation Error:
scheme:'scheme' should match pattern "^[a-z][a-z0-9+.-]*$"
scheme:should be array
scheme:should match exactly one schema in oneOf
This is likely a problem with your app.json, or app.config.js
Request ID: cfe64ce7-97c0-42b0-b11b-6f7fbc895b03
Error: GraphQL request failed.

Below is my app.json code

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "JKDaily",
    "slug": "JKDaily",
    "version": "8.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "scheme": "tabsRouting",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "usesAppleSignIn": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.jkdaily.com",
      "googleServicesFile": "./GoogleService-Info.plist",
      "useFrameworks": "static",
      "infoPlist": {
        "NSUserTrackingUsageDescription": "This identifier will be used to deliver personalized ads to you."
      }
    },
    "android": {
      "googleServicesFile": "./google-services.json",
      "versionCode": 30,
      "permissions": [
        "com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"
      ],
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },
      "package": "com.jkdaily.com"
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "plugins": [
      "expo-router",
      "@react-native-firebase/app",
      "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin",
      "expo-apple-authentication",
      [
        "expo-build-properties",
        {
          "ios": {
            "useFrameworks": "static"
          },
          "android": {
            "enableProguardInReleaseBuilds": true,
            "extraProguardRules": "-keep public class com.horcrux.svg.** {*;}",
            "allowBackup": false
          }
        }
      ],
      [
        "expo-tracking-transparency",
        {
          "userTrackingPermission": "This identifier will be used to deliver personalized ads to you."
        }
      ],
      
      [
      "react-native-fbsdk-next", {
        "appID": "18xxxxxxxxx",
        "clientToken": "4xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "displayName": "Facebook SDK",
        "scheme": "fb18xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "advertiserIDCollectionEnabled": false,
        "autoLogAppEventsEnabled": false,
        "isAutoInitEnabled": true,
        "iosUserTrackingPermission": "This identifier will be used to deliver personalized ads to you."
      }
      ]
    ],
    "extra": {
      "router": {
        "origin": false
      },
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "324798xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
      }
    },
    "runtimeVersion": {
      "policy": "appVersion"
    },
    "updates": {
      "url": "https://u.expo.dev/3247982d-6237-496xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    }
  },
```